# PNG display in PIL broken on OS X Mavericks?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, python-imaging-library, osx-mavericks

I've noticed that PNG images aren't displaying in Tkinter apps using ImageTk.PhotoImage in OS X Mavericks. But, GIFs and JPEGs display fine. There's no error printed or exception thrown and debugging the code shows the image is read and has the correct height & width. Here's a simplified example:

```
import Tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

logo_file = 'test.png'
#logo_file = 'test.gif'


class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.minsize(width=512, height=256)
        self.master.config()

        self.pack()

        self.main_frame = Tkinter.Frame()
        self.some_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(logo_file))

        some_label = Tkinter.Label(self.main_frame, image=self.some_image)
        some_label.config()
        some_label.pack(side='top')

        self.main_frame.place(in_=self.master, anchor='c', relx=.5, rely=.5)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

If you use a GIF the image will be displayed, but using a PNG it will not. Again, this is only happening on OS X Mavericks, Mountain Lion works fine. I've tried re-installing (compiling PIL) with no luck, as well as trying a new virtualenv.

Is there perhaps some PNG attribute I need to set correctly when creating/saving the PNG? Or is this a bug in PIL or Tkinter or OS X?

**Update to add some details**

I'm using:

- Python 2.7.5 (/usr/bin/python)
- PIL 1.1.7 (compiled using pip)

This is on a machine that was just updated to Mavericks from Mountain Lion, and previously had PIL installed, and I haven't messed with the system Python shipped by Apple.

**Update 2 Pillow setup summary**

I installed Pillow 2.2.1 and it says it has PNG support:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version      Pillow 2.2.1
platform     darwin 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04)
             [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- TIFF G3/G4 (experimental) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
*** WEBP support not available
*** WEBPMUX support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also uninstalled and re-installed libpng using brew (libpng 1.5.14). I then re-installed Pillow to make sure it built with it, though I think it uses zlib.

**Update 3 trying to build Python 2.7.5**

Perhaps the issue is with zlib, trying to compile Python 2.7.5 I get this:

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _sqlite3           _ssl             
bsddb185           dbm                dl               
gdbm               imageop         linuxaudiodev    
nis                ossaudiodev        readline        
spwd               sunaudiodev        zlib
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


Failed to build these modules:
_tkinter
```

Comment: Did you install PIL (and other stuff) on Mountain Lion and then update, or do a clean install on Mavericks (or clean-install some things but not others, or build a `py2app`-style app on Mountain Lion then run it on Mavericks, or…). Also, are you using Apple's pre-installed Python 2.7, or some other Python (and, if the latter, which, and how did you install it)? And what version of PIL and how did you install it?

Comment: Your code works for me on 64bit Python 2.7. Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I ask because on my system, I had Python 3.3.2 installed under 10.8 with PNG working, then upgraded to 10.9, then `pip-3.3 install --upgrade pillow` worked _but failed to find libpng_, so I ended up with a PIL with no PNG support. I only figured this out when I uninstalled and reinstalled pillow and read the full output. I fixed the problem by using Homebrew to `brew install libpng` (and then reinstalling pillow, of course).

Comment: updated the question w/some system details. @octref you're on Mavericks?

Comment: More generally, can you uninstall and reinstall pillow (if you were using old-school PIL instead… switch), and paste the "PIL SETUP SUMMARY" section somewhere? If it didn't find zlib or libpng or anything else that's required for PNG support, it'll say so there.

Comment: No, I'm using windows.

Comment: @octref: Why did you think that your Windows experience would be relevant? We already know it works for the OP on his 64-bit OS X Mountain Lion box…

Comment: @abarnert To exclude the possibility that it's the code's program rather than environment's.

Comment: @octref: The fact that it runs on OS X Mountain Lion already does that.

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is that your PIL was built without PNG support, or with only partial PNG support, on your Mavericks machine.

If PIL can't find both libpng and libz where it wants to, you won't have complete PNG support. And after upgrading from Mountain Lion to Mavericks, this seems to sometimes be a problem.

This *may* not be the same problem you're having. For example, it could be down to Apple using a buggy version of Tcl/Tk again (as they infamously did in Snow Leopard). But it's definitely worth trying.

With [`Pillow`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow), and some versions of old-school PIL (but really, if you're not using Pillow, you almost definitely should be), the end of the install process gives you a friendly "PIL SETUP SUMMARY" section that shows you all the important configuration stuff.

I had the exact same problem with Pillow 2.2.1 on a locally-built Python 3.3.2. I solved it by using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to install libpng, then rebuilding Pillow:

```
$ brew install libpng
$ pip-3.3 uninstall pillow
$ pip-3.3 install pillow
```

Comment: thanks, I did uninstalled / re-installed libpng, then installed pillow, but still not working. I'll try a fresh Python in a virtualenv.

Comment: @Pathétique: Oh well, it was worth a try… When I get a chance (I'm not in front of a Mavericks machine right now), I'll try installing pillow into Apple's Python 2.7.5 and see what happens.

Comment: Hadn't even heard of Pillow before this post. You just saved me A LOT of troubleshooting. Pillow solved this exact problem I was having on Mavericks. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: @LeachyPeachy: I wish the PIL docs had a link to Pillow… but then the reason Pillow exists in the first place is that PIL and its docs are apparently dead and nobody can update them. So, people have to find Pillow by accident.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem and I did the following.  It seems to be fixed.

```
sudo unistall pillow
xcode-select --install
pip install pillow
```

It seems to be working great. I also installed all the items below, but it seems you have it already installed

```
brew install libtiff libjpeg libpng webp littlecms
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fix the problem for me. I think I'll try completely re-installing Xcode and the command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Pillow dependencies?

```
pip uninstall Pillow
brew install libtiff libjpeg webp littlecms
pip install Pillow
```

You will need [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh/) to execute the brew command.

Comment: Petr, thanks but I've tried (and re-tried) this with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Pillow from homebrew (brew install Pillow), all necessary dependencies will be installed automatically. Problem solved.